# OS compatibility for older Mac

Tags: macos, mac, audio, apple-music, power-mac

Can my Mac Pro (Mid 2010) use Mojave? Right now I am using 10.13.6.

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Could be "supported by apps" (no) or "can be made to run" (yes). If the latter you could consider something more recent than Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'officially' put Mojave on a 2010 Mac Pro, once you put a Metal2 GPU in it. The barrier to upgrade drops away, no further hack required.

Such as an AMD[ATI] Radeon HD 7950 will work. Make sure to get one that's already Mac-flashed, otherwise you won't be able to see the screen before login or use FileVault.

Avoid NVidia, they don't have drivers after High Sierra. AMD drivers are built into the OS.

Once the card is in, the update to Mojave will require a firmware update as part of the OS update. The instructions say to hold the power button until it flashes - in fact you need to hold it longer; it will eventually reboot itself, then you can let go. This took a lot of trial & error at the time.

Answer (score 1):

No. High Sierra is the limit<sup>1</sup> for a 2010 Mac... unless you go for an unofficial [dosdude1](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/) type hack.

Note that if you have a *[Metal capable GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API))* then Mojave might work on a 2010 Mac Pro.

---

<sup>1</sup> See Wikipedia for the official supported platforms against the Mac models: [High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra#System_requirements), [Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave#System_requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Linux (Many Distributions will work) I use LMDE6 on my 2010 Mac Pro 5,1 or one could use Unix (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, GhostBSD), and have a supported OS to use on your 2010 Mac Pro.

If you require Mac or Windows Software one could setup a Virtual Machine and run Windows or Mac software this way. Or, use Play on Linux/Wine to run Windows Software or something like Darling to run Mac Software with out installing a full Virtual Machine.

Comment: Does the EULA allow Mojave to be run in in a VM?

Comment: Not sure about the EULA in regards to VM on a 2010 Mac Pro and Mac OS Mojave, as High Sierra, is the latest Mac OS supported on the 2010 Mac Pro. In Testing I have installed multiple OS Types as a Virtual Machine.